# Choosing a Mysql Datatype

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes, abstract-data-type

For data sets like: `ecb1bcf6-c7a6-572e-a44d-d6e3298486b7`

What's the best way (as far as datatypes) to store this in mysql?

This value will be READ-ONLY, NOT updated, ever.

Comment: is the string "ecb1bcf6-c7a6-572e-a44d-d6e3298486b7 " is a value as a whole or every part is a value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about varchar?

```
columnName VARCHAR(255)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use 
`varchar` type it is the best suits your need
Best Regards